# (Individual SQL queries) vs (Single SQL query & looping through that data) Which one is better?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, for-loop

I have a requirement to get data from SQL database for the list of items given by the user.
Example, if a user uploads a .csv file containing 1000 item ids, making 1000 SQL queries by item_id would be a better option ? or getting whole database table data in a single SQL query and looping over that data would be a better option ?

Comment: Can't you upload that 1000 items into temporary table and join with your main table to get data set back easier? That way you won't have where ID IN (....) ... nor you won't have 1000 of selects. With SQL try to work with data sets, not making complex query or 1000 selects

Comment: @Veljko89 Thanks for your input, I am not going to make complex query, I am thinking to get whole data in a single call (using select * from table), and loop over that data through for/while loop to get my required dataset.

Comment: Yes but, what I am trying to say is that you could import that .csv file into new table, then just do simple JOIN and get what you need. That seems as fastest way to get what you want

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea, I will try that, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments:

The best way would be to create a single-column `item_search`table in the database; put the 1000 item identifiers into a text file, one identifier per row, and then to use MySQL's load functionality to load that file into your search table.

Then use:

```
SELECT
  item_id,
, name
, <any other columns>
FROM items i
INNER JOIN item_search s
ON i.item_id = s.item_id
```

to export the data.

The most expensive part in a SQL connection is always accepting SQL requests and initiating and ending SQL requests. This way, you have two requests; the load and the export; the other way, you have 1000 requests.